# Floating Point Computation Precision in C++

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, precision

I wanted to implement something like floating point precision where the template function controls the number of the digits after the point(.) (or the fraction)?

```cpp
  template <typename T, unsigned int PRECISION = 4>
  constexpr T precision (T v) noexcept
      requires (is_floating_point_v<T>)
  {
    long digits = static_cast<long>(pow(10, PRECISION));
    long temp = v * digits;
    return 
        static_cast<T>(temp)
      / static_cast<T>(digits);
  }
```

Here a naive approach. I am not very happy with the *pow* function above to compute the digits. Is there something more Elegant? Like:

```
1e4, but the number *4* is not substitutable by *PRECISION*
10^PRECISION does not work
```

Is there something to express the *pow* function at compile time?

Alternative would be that, but I don't like the interface.

```cpp
  template <typename T, unsigned int PRECISION = 10000>
  constexpr T precision (T v) noexcept
      requires (is_floating_point_v<T>)
  {
    long temp = v * PRECISION;
    return 
        static_cast<T>(temp)
      / static_cast<T>(PRECISION);
  }
```

Comment: You might create a `constexpr`/`consteval` function for a non floating `pow`.

Comment: What you're writing is probably _fixed-point_, not floating.  There are moves towards `constexpr std::pow()`, but for integer powers it's easy enough to write your own `constexpr` implementation.

Comment: As `T` is deducible, `template <unsigned int PRECISION = 4, typename T>` is probably easier to use.

Comment: Functions like this are generally a bad idea and will not do what you want except in specific limited situations or when crafted by an expert. In C implementations that use binary-based floating-point, which is nearly all of them, it is actually impossible to “control the number of digits after the point” because a number such as 1.234 cannot be represented in the format (just something close). Additionally, rounding issues in `v * digits` will sometimes cause undesired results in the following truncation to `long`.

Comment: That is true. But I want to have something with less precision, just 4 until 8 digits behind the point. This should be applicable by float or double. And for my concerns I consider enough. Do you know a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution to this question would be something like this:

```cpp
  template <unsigned int EXP>
  constexpr long pow10x () noexcept
      requires (EXP >= 0)
  {
    long result = 1;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<EXP; ++i)
      result*=10;
    return result;
  }

  template <unsigned int PRECISION = 4, typename T>
  constexpr T precision (T v) noexcept
      requires (is_floating_point_v<T> && PRECISION>=1 && PRECISION<=8)
  {
    long digits = pow10x<PRECISION>();
    long temp = v * digits;
    return 
        static_cast<T>(temp)
      / static_cast<T>(digits);
  }
```

I thought there is something like a builtin *pow* function for integers as constexpr or even a simple expression. Well to write that function isn't difficult.

Comment: You are right. I took it out